# my custom site.css inside my asp.net mvc-5 is not overriding the built-in styles

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. and i have the following inside my shared _layout view:-

```
<link id="bs-css" href="~/Content/css/bootstrap-cerulean.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="~/Content/css/charisma-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/start/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/templete")
```

so mainly i am referencing the built-in bootstrap .css files first, then i am referecning the bundle `@Styles.Render("~/Content/templete")` which contain our site.css. so this means that the site.css should override the built-in .css files, since i am referencing the site.css after them...

now the problem i am facing is that i have the following style define inside my site.css:-

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

to show a red boarder if an input have any validation error. now inside my application i will not get this faulty behavior as follow:-

[image]

where as shown in the picture the input field will not have any red boarder unlike the drop-down field. now as shown in the firebug , the following css rules which are defined inside the bootstrap-cerulean.css will override the site.css style (although i am referencing the site.css after the bootstrap-cerulean.css):-

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
    color: #555555;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

so can anyone adivce how i can force this style , to have the intended effect on the input fields ?

```
.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute selectors have higher specificity than class selectors.  Even though your class selector is later in the stylesheet, it's still overridden by the more specific attribute sectors higher in the file.

```css
input[type=text] {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.error {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  border: 1px solid #F88;
}
```

```html
<input class="error" type="text">
```

Try adding the attribute part to your error class to increase the specificity of it.

```css
input[type=text] {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

input[type=text].error {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  border: 1px solid #F88;
}
```

```html
<input class="error" type="text">
```

I haven't read it, but this article looks pretty good: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: so why i did not get this on the dropdown field ? i mean on the dropdown list it will have a red boarder and red background... second question. in my case the .input-validation-error will automatically apply to any field that have validation error (this is part of the MVC framework validation) , so not sure if i have the ability to define  class="error" in my case...so i still need to do the styling inside  the .input-validation-error.....

Comment: @johnG bootstrap doesn't attempt to style select items.  They are notorious for being difficult to work with.  I usually grab a javascript library to make it have the bootstrap styles rather than deal with all the browser specific styles.  I think bootstrap doesn't even try to style it, but if it does, it'll use `select { ... }` which has lower specificity than a class selector.  It's not using the attribute selector (e.g. `[type=whatever]`) which is why the other selectors have higher specificity.

Comment: so i think this will work in my case if i define this css rule inside my custom site.css :- input[type=text].input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}// is this a valid thing to do?

Comment: @johnG for the second question, you have two options.  in your stylesheet you can shotgun it with `input[type="text"].input-validation-error, input[type="password"].input-validation-error,  ... .input-validation-error` or you can use `!important`.  the stated purpose of `!important` is to override specificity, so it's within the acceptable uses of `!important`.  I would go with the first option, however.  So, yes, you are correct.  Adding the extra `input[type=whatever]` parts to your selector is appropriate.

Comment: so using this for text fields will be fine :- input[type=text].input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}????

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  That should work in your case and it's how I would do it too.

Comment: @johnG You're welcome.  Glad I could help.  And sorry for my slow typing.  We kind of ran into eachother there a couple times in these comments. :P